# using std::transform on a 2d C array into a 1d C array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, stl, stl-algorithm

I am trying to use `std::transform` to convert a simple 2d array (of `Foo` structs) into a 1d (transformed) array of `Bar` structs.

```
// convert 2d array of Foo structs to 1d array of Bar structs
// suitable for constructing a Baz struct.
Foo array2d[3][2] = 
{ 
    { 
        {1,2}, {3,4} 
    }, 
    { 
        {5,6}, {7,8} 
    }, 
    { 
        {9,10}, {11,12} 
    } 
};
```

The conversion in this simple example just reverses the field order as both structs are really the same type.  In my application these are completely different types.

```
using Foo = struct {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
};

using Bar = struct {
    uint32_t c;
    uint32_t d;
};
```

The idea is that this 1d array of Bar structs could be used to construct a `Baz` struct.

I am having trouble with the lambda converter(s).  I believe that the outer one takes a row at at time while the inner one takes a column at a time where the actual Foo->Bar conversion takes place.  In the live demo, I had to comment out the std::transform taking the 2d array and replace it with a flattened version where I cast the 2d array to a 1d array (of size row times col).  This worked flawlessly - but I was trying to stick to the parameter types without having to resort to the reinterpret_cast<>.

```
    std::vector<Bar> array1d;
    array1d.reserve(Baz::gArraySize);
#if 0
    // I don't know how to use the transform on the 2d array
    std::transform(std::cbegin(array2d), std::cend(array2d),
        std::back_inserter(array1d),
        [](const Foo(&rRow)[Baz::gNumCols]) {
        std::transform(std::cbegin(rRow), std::cend(rRow),
            [](const Foo& rNext) -> Bar {
                // reverse the order of the fields
                return Bar{ rNext.b, rNext.a };
            });
        });
#else
    // Only workaround is to cast the 2d array to a 1d array using reinterpret cast<>
    const auto& special = reinterpret_cast<const Foo(&)[Baz::gArraySize]>(array2d);
    // I don't know how to use the transform on the 2d array
    std::transform(std::cbegin(special), std::cend(special),
        std::back_inserter(array1d),
        [](const Foo& rNext) -> Bar {
            // reverse the order of the fields
            return Bar{ rNext.b, rNext.a };
        });
#endif
    // construct from transformed 2d array
    Baz myBaz(reinterpret_cast<const Bar(&)[Baz::gArraySize]>(array1d[0]));
    std::cout << myBaz;
```

producing the expected output as follows:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
Bar{c=2, d=1},
Bar{c=4, d=3},
Bar{c=6, d=5},
Bar{c=8, d=7},
Bar{c=10, d=9},
Bar{c=12, d=11},
```

The structs are in C like array form as these come from an external source.  I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is possible with std::transform, but I would like to use STL algorithms rather than unravel the loops by hand.

I created the following [**live coliru demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8c0972dbdad2de4) to show what I was trying to achieve - but its got many errors with the transform in place.  Note that the array being passed to Baz depends on the fact that the std::vector allocates data structures contiguously in memory (this is guaranteed by the STL).

```
struct Baz {
    constexpr static int gNumRows = 3;
    constexpr static int gNumCols = 2;
    constexpr static int gArraySize = gNumRows * gNumCols;
    Bar arrayField[gArraySize];
    // explicit constructor from C style fixed size array.
    explicit Baz(const Bar(&rParam)[gArraySize])
        : arrayField{}
    {
        std::memcpy(arrayField, rParam, gArraySize * sizeof(Bar));
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(
        std::ostream& os, const Baz& rhs) {
        for (auto next : rhs.arrayField) {
            os << "Bar{c=" << next.c << ", d=" << next.d << "},\n";
        }
        return os;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda you pass to the outer `transform` doesn't return anything and it really can't because it supposed to return **one** value for each element of the input range (your two-dimensional array). But each element of that array has **two** values so every iteration of the `transform` would produce two values when it should produce one, that's why you can't use `transform` here.

Given this, it would be a lot easier and a lot more readable to use simple loops here:

```
for (auto &&row : array2d)
    for (auto &&foo : row)
        oneDimArray.push_back(Bar{ foo.b, foo.a });
```

and leave STL algorithms for the cases when they actually make your life easier :).

Comment: thanks very helpful, I will try to see if I can get my specific example to work with the syntax you provided, BTW the outer transform receives a row - at least that is what I thought it would receive.  BTW the auto && syntax - is that needed for c++17 - I thought that (auto row : array2d) would do the same.  BTW I tweaked the example while you were making your answer, sorry - your answer is still valid - I was just showing a side by side working/nonworking versions in the live demo

Comment: @johnco3, `auto` without reference actually would create a copy of the element. `auto &&` is actually the recommended syntax for range-based `for` loops since C++11, because it would bind to whatever value category is returned from dereferencing the iterator.

Comment: @johnco3, your outer transform does indeed receive a row but it should return one value while the row consists of two elements.

Comment: I could have sworn that I read there was a special optimization for c++17 where (auto n : array) would bind n to a universal reference (&&).  I'm trying to find the source.

Comment: @johnco3, ah, I misunderstood your question. I don't think it changed in C++17 since it would break existing code. I think there was a proposal (at least) to write `for (var : range)` without type at all which will automatically mean the same as `auto &&`.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up and thanks for your answer which I accepted.